# How to do -1 on a specific byte of an integer in C#?

Tags: c#, byte, bit-shift

I have an integer u=101057541.

Binary, this is equal to: ***00000110*** 00000110 00000100 00000101

Now, I regard each byte as a seperate decimal (so 6, 6, 4, 5 in this case).
I want to subtract -1 from the first byte, resulting in 6-1=5.
I try to do this as follows:

```
int West = u | (((u>>24) - 1) << 24);
```

However, the result is the same as when I **ADD** 1 to this byte. Can someone explain why and tell me how to subtract -1 from this byte?

UPDATE:
Thus, the result I want is the following binary number:

***00000101*** 00000110 00000100 00000101

Comment: You subtracted -1, alright.

Comment: if you have u = 1; it will be `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001` => 0 0 0 1, what would you like to do here 0-1 or 1-1 ?

Comment: I wonder who up-votes a question like this on SO.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick reply. I now understand what I did wrong and used masking to get the proper result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're "or"-ing that byte back in:

```
 u | (((u>>24) - 1) << 24);
```

should be

```
 (u & mask) | (((u>>24) - 1) << 24);
```

where `mask` is everything except the byte you're playing with.

You might find unsafe code easier:

```
int i = 101057541;
byte* b = (byte*)&i;
b[3]--; // note CPU endianness is important here
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

You can do the same thing without `unsafe` using "spans" if you're using all the latest bits;

```
int i = 101057541;
var bytes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<int, byte>(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref i, 1));
bytes[3]--; // note CPU endianness is important here
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

or you could use a "union" via a `struct` with explicit layout - so 4 bytes overlapping 1 int:

```
var x = new Int32Bytes();
x.Value = 101057541;
x.Byte3--; // note CPU endianness is important here
Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
```

with:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Int32Bytes
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Value;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte Byte0;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte Byte1;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte Byte2;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte Byte3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive reply. I did it with masking as your proposed. 
Something like this: (u & 16777215) | (((u >> 24) - 1) << 24);

Comment: @RutgerMauritz if 16777215 is 0x00FFFFFF, then sure

Comment: I did change it in 0x00FFFFFF yes. However, I now want to do the same thing for the 2nd byte of my integer, for which case I try using 0xFF00FFFF. However, in this case I get the error "cannot impl. convert type 'long' to 'int' ". Do you know why this happens? (I'm very new to C#)

Comment: @RutgerMauritz the compiler is twitchy about constants that hit the last bit - it may be easier to use `~0xFF0000` or `~(0xFF << 16)`, but it shows why the other approaches can be simpler...

Comment: Thanks a lot. This masking seems to work for me though. I need to build a certain program for my studies, where they pay a lot of attention to time-efficiency. I have to use this byte arithmetic in a certain while-loop, isn't it then the most efficient way to use masking?

Comment: @RutgerMauritz not necessarily, no; you'd be amazed how efficient the span code is in netcoreapp2.1 - **huge** JIT work to make that blazing; and `unsafe` has always been fast - it is just uglier. Keep in mind that although both the `unsafe` and `Span*` code might look gnarly, during JIT most of that literally evaporates to nothing - so essentially all it becomes is an in-place ref decr - that's **less** work than shifting and masking. For real answers on performance, a tool like benchmarkdotnet would be recommended (which is free, etc)

Comment: @RutgerMauritz I'd be very hard pressed to say which of these is "faster" without using benchmarkdotnet: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxNMAfAAgZgARYBMeAwgLABQA3pXnQQIwBseArgHZQQBmceAluxh4AInADGCAKqcecABSDhrAJS16NCvW14AbhAR5gAT3hQ8AXjwAyVgG51Oo6bhQA2jgC6AWm8OtTgQA7Gz+2gC+jowsSqISCADKABb83DCKQmxqAXSagcF08qw2eAAMAB6lpQBitXXZ+doYePKtrAB87YQALCp43ngMfQA8w3g9KmH0kRThQA

Answer (score 1):

When you subtract 1 from 00000110 the result is 00000101. You OR this with the original value and you get 0000111, which is like if you added 1.

As a one-liner to your problem, you should mask out the region of the bits you are manipulating.:

int West = (u & 0x00FFFFFF) | ((((u & 0xFF000000)>>24) - 1) << 24);

Comment: the mask on the right here is redundant - you'll throw away the other bits during the shift; it would be more important for interior segments

Comment: @Marc: you are right, I thought of it and I know in the current case it is redundant. In general it is good to have (defensive coding). Also u and West are signed integers.